# ¿Cuándo fue la palabra "ítem" agregada al DLE?

Tags: historia

¿Ha sido la palabra ítem siempre parte del DLE o fue agregada recientemente?

Al principio pensé que se trataba de un anglicismo, pero al parecer proviene del latín y es la primera vez que la veo en el diccionario.

Comment: si puedo imaginar el uso del significado latino original, 
pero no del sustantivo:  4. m. Inform. Cada uno de los elementos que forman parte de un conjunto de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) se puede comprobar que aparece ya desde el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495 y siguientes.
En cuanto al DRAE en concreto, desde la primera edición del mismo, el [*Diccionario de Autoridades*](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=28275&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA%5FINDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA%5Fform%2Ehtml), en 1734:

> **ITEM**. adv. Latino, que se usa para hacer distinción de artículos, o capítulos, en alguna escritura o instrumento: y tambien por señal de adición o repetición de lo que se ha dicho. Dícese vulgarmente Item más, aunque el más está de sobra. QUEV. Mus. 6. Rom. 49.
>   Su modo de proceder 
>   es un puro testamento,
>   porque todo es item más,
>   después de mandar su cuerpo.

EDICION

La acepción informática por la que el OP pregunta en un comentario a su pregunta no puede ser, evidentemente, tan antigua, pero aparece ya en la edición de 1984:

> *Informát*. Conjunto secuencial de caracteres que pertenecen a un mismo dato.